# Find $S$ where $S=\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {13}}+\sqrt[3]{5-2 \sqrt {13}}$, why am I getting an imaginary number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\large S=\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {13}}+\sqrt[3]{5-2 \sqrt {13}}$

Multiplying by conjugate:

$\large S=\dfrac {-3}{\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {13}}-\sqrt[3]{5-2 \sqrt {13}}}$

From the original:

$\large S-2\sqrt[3]{5-2 \sqrt {13}}
=\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {13}}-\sqrt[3]{5-2 \sqrt {13}}$

Substituting:

$\large S=\dfrac{-3}{S-2\sqrt[3]{5-2 \sqrt {13}}}$

This leads to a quadratic equation in $\large S$ which I checked in wolframalpha and I got imaginary solutions. Why does this happen? I am not looking for an answer telling me how to solve this problem, I just want to know why this is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Why is that the conjugate?

Comment: What do you mean why, you can multiply the expression by whatever you want.

Comment: It looks to me like you may have taken the conjugate in the square-root sense. But these are cube roots.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Yes thanks I just figured that out, the -3 in the numerator is wrong

Comment: *Complex number* is a more adequate term.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Ok thank you I will

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not right: the conjugate to $S$ is
$$
\left[\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {13}}\right]^2-\sqrt[3]{5+2 \sqrt {13}}\sqrt[3] {5-2 \sqrt {13}}+\left[\sqrt[3]{5-2 \sqrt {13}}\right]^2.
$$

Answer (score 5):

You can find quickly $S$ if you note that $$5+2\sqrt{13}=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^3$$ and similarly for  $5-2\sqrt{13}$.

Comment: wow${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ The standard trick that I saw in high school.

Comment: You assume that $a,b$ satisfy $5+2\sqrt{13} = (a+b\sqrt{13})^3 = (a^3+39ab^2)+(3a^2b+13b^3)\sqrt{13}$ and try to find nice values for $a$ and $b$. As it turns out, $a = b = \frac{1}{2}$ work.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably better to cube $S$:
$$S^3 = (5 + 2\sqrt{13}) + 3\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {13}}\sqrt[3] {5- 2 \sqrt {13}}\bigg(\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {13}} + \sqrt[3] {5-2 \sqrt {13}}\bigg) + (5 - 2\sqrt{13})$$ 
$$= 10 + 3\sqrt[3] {5^2-(2 \sqrt {13})^2}S$$
$$= 10 -9S$$
So $S$ satisfies the equation $S^3 + 9S -10 = 0$. The polynomial $S^3 + 9S -10$ factorizes as $(S-1)(S^2 + S - 10) = 0$, so you expect that $S = 1$.

But you still have to make sure $S$ is not one of the roots of $S^2 + S - 10 = 0$, given by ${\displaystyle -{1 \over 2} \pm {\sqrt{41} \over 2}}$. For this, note that the absolute value of each of these roots is greater than ${\sqrt{41} \over 2} - {1 \over 2} >  {\sqrt{36} \over 2} - {1 \over 2} > 2$. On the other hand $\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {13}}$ is less than $\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {16}} = \sqrt[3]{13} < 2$. The other term $\sqrt[3] {5-2 \sqrt {13}}$ is negative and of smaller absolute value, so we conclude that $0 < S < 2$, and the only possibility is that $S = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note the identity $$x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)+3xyz$$

So that if $x+y+z=0$ we have $x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$

This is often useful with cubic expressions like this. Take $x=-S;\text{  } y=\sqrt[3] {5+2 \sqrt {13}};\text{  }z=\sqrt[3]{5-2 \sqrt {13}}$

Then we have$$-S^3+5+2\sqrt{13}+5-2\sqrt{13}=-3S\sqrt[3]{25-52}$$ whence $$S^3+9S-10=0$$

and you recover the cubic of which $S$ is a root. As it happens this is easy to factor, and you need to identify the root which corresponds to the expression you were given. I shall not repeat what Zarrax has put from this point on. But I think the trick is worth knowing, as it hugely simplifies the arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you factor a cubic equation such as this? Do you test for possible rational roots?

Comment: @Ovi - indeed, as Zarrax has shown. When these expressions are set as puzzles they normally turn out well. The original expression tends to be what you get by plugging the coefficients into the formula for the roots of a (reduced - ie no $x^2$ term) cubic - and this method recovers the cubic in question. The only real reason for asking the question is that there is an easier way of finding the root than using the formula. Examining the method here will illuminate the connection.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, we'll let $S = a+b$ where $a=\sqrt[3]{5+2\sqrt{13}}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{5-2\sqrt{13}}$.

Note that $S^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3=5+2\sqrt{13}+5-2\sqrt{13}+3a^2b+3ab^2$.

$S^3+9S-10=3a^2b+3ab^2+9a+9b=3a(ab+3)+3b(ab+3)=3(a+b)(ab+3)=3S(ab+3)$.

Now, $ab=\sqrt[3]{(5+2\sqrt{13})(5-2\sqrt{13})}=\sqrt[3]{25-52}=\sqrt[3]{-27}=-3$. So $ab+3=0$. Thus, we see that $S$ is a root of the cubic equation $x^3+9x-10$. It is clear that $1$ is a root so the cubic is equal to $(x-1)(x^2+x+10)$. By the Quadratic Formula, the other two roots are imaginary. Thus $S=1$.